# Unable to install MongoDB PHP driver on XAMPP Windows

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, php-mongodb

I am using Windows OS (64-bit) and running XAMPP(PHP 5.4.7). I tried installing the PHP MongoDB Driver but it is not reflecting on the phpinfo() page.

I followed the same steps as listed:

1. I downloaded php_mongo-1.3.2RC1.zip (latest one) from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads
2. I extracted the folder and copied the `php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9.dll` file and pasted in `C://XAMPP/php/ext/`.
   My PHP extension build says API20100525,TS,VC9
3. I opened php.ini file and i inserted `;extension=php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9.dll` at the last line.

I then looked at the `phpinfo()` page as well as I tried the

```
echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
```

It says it is not loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing the **;** from the beginning of `;extension=php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9.dll` in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the steps as mentioned in the question, xampp may not be able to load the ".dll" file. Just ensure to add the path of the ".dll" file's folder to the environment variable as a system variable path.

I was facing same issue, then after adding the path of the ".dll" file's folder to the environment variable as a system variable path, it worked. It is then able to find the file.

At the end that was the only step which was stopping xampp to load the ".dll" file, although it was present in that folder. Often people miss this step as it is no where pointed out clearly.